# Sum amont in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this request, but t does'nt work well.

```
select date_format(date, "%Y-%m-%d") as month,
                                           sum(value) as total
                                    from :table_orders_sales_commission
                                    where date_sub(now(), interval 12 month) <= date
                                    group by month
```

the result is :

```
2017-04-02 4.6440
2017-04-03 2.6200
```

How to have the sum on one month  (4.644+2.62)?

Comment: you need to extract month from date and group by the same then you will get the what you want

Comment: You just need to remove the day portion when formatting the month field.  Currently you're group by includes the day as well.  date_format(date, '%Y-%m') as month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use MONTH function and use it as group by

```
select MONTH(date_format(date, "%Y-%m-%d")) as month,
sum(value) as total
from :table_orders_sales_commission
where date_sub(now(), interval 12 month) <= date
group by MONTH(date_format(date, "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Answer (score 2):

you are calling month a date. This means that you are summing up all the values for each day. I'd do something like this:

```
select date, MONTH(date) as month,
sum(value) as total
from :table_orders_sales_commission
where date_sub(now(), interval 12 month) <= date
group by month
```

`MONTH` will return the value of the month only from the field and you can aggregate by month while doing the sum calculation

Note that the standard date format in mysql is already what you want to set, no need to manipulate it so I removed the part related to `date_format(date, "%Y-%m-%d")` but you can keep it if you have a custom date field mask

Comment: There are several ways of getting the results you need but this is probably the simplest and best approach.